# change directory failing in cmd prompt

Tags: perl, batch-file, cmd

I have two files :

- perl file "Test.pl" at the location "C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15"
- bat file "TestBatch.bat" at the loc : "C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14"

The perl file "Test.pl" makes a call to the batch file "TestBatch.bat" and then the batch file should try to set the current path to be "C:\A1\A11\" and change the directory to "C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14"

But it fails saying the "System cannot find the path specified". I want it to change directory to "C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14"

Following is the code of both the files

Test.pl

```
my $abs_bat_file_loc = "C:\\A1\\A11\\A12\\A13\\B14\\TestBatch.bat";
system ($abs_bat_file_loc);
```

TestBatch.bat

```
set current_path=%CD%\..\..\..\..\
cd A12\A13\B14
```

**Note** : I ran the perl file in cmd prompt in following way:

```
cd C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15
perl Test.pl
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `set` changes variable contents, not current active directory. `cd` changes current active directory.

Comment: In TestBatch.bat, I tried removing set current_path=%CD%\..\..\..\..\
And only use cd C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14

Still it does not change the directory to B14

Comment: You may want to use [`cd /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) to change the drive also, if applicable...

Comment: You are changing the directory, BUT the directory that you are changing is the current active directory of the `cmd` instance that is executing the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`set current_path=%CD%\..\..\..\..\
cd A12\A13\B14`

Why not replace it with

`PushD %~dp0`

this will force the working directory in the batch file to be the full location of where the batch file is located (eg; C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14)

Comment: I tried with what you suggested.
Modified the TestBatch.bat to only have this line:
PushD %~dp0

The cmd prompt still shows as:
C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15>

and not as C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14

Comment: The cmd prompt looks like:

C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15>perl Test.pl

C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15>PushD C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\B14\

C:\A1\A11\A12\A13\A14\A15>